# How to set label name under the bars of Bar Chart using core plot in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I am unable to set the label name exact below the bar of bar chart. How to change its origin value to move right side so that it will be exact below of the bar. Please find the image here in this link: [i.imgur.com/kJEeM.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ez70.png)

I am search for solution, yet I did not get any solution please help me out of this....

Answer (score 0):

You should use axis labels on the x-axis. There are several example apps included with Core Plot that show how to format dates on the axes. If you already have the text of the labels, you can use custom labels instead. There are examples of that technique, too. The linked image doesn't show an axis line--just set the axis and tick line styles to nil to suppress drawing the axis line.